# Issues Fixing data Appropriately into Jquery Orgchart using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, orgchart

I have been thinking on how to appropriately fit data from database into jquery organisational chart in such a way that a user gets to see those who have registered under their referral link and the people the referrals have registered as well in an organizational tree view. A user gets know those under him/her.

I already already have this [Orgchart](http://bitsplenda.com/tree/)

But i want it to look like [Color-coded Orgchart](http://bitsplenda.com/test/)

Any Help will be appreciated please

**PHP CODE**

```
function getConnection() {
$dbhost="127.0.0.1";
$dbuser="root";
$dbpass="";
$dbname="tree";
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
return $dbh;
}
$sql = "select id as memberId, parent as parentId, user as otherInfo from users";
try {
    $db = getConnection();
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
    $wines = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $db = null;
    echo json_encode($wines);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.orgchart.css"/>
<script src="jquery.orgchart.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
var members;
$.ajax({
url:'load.php',
async:false,
success:function(data){
    members=$.parseJSON(data)
}
})

    //memberId,parentId,otherInfo
    for(var i = 0; i < members.length; i++){

        var member = members[i];

        if(i==0){
            $("#mainContainer").append("<li id="+member.memberId+">"+member.otherInfo+"</li>")
        }else{

            if($('#pr_'+member.parentId).length<=0){
              $('#'+member.parentId).append("<ul id='pr_"+member.parentId+"'><li id="+member.memberId+">"+member.otherInfo+"</li></ul>")
            }
            else{
              $('#pr_'+member.parentId).append("<li id="+member.memberId+">"+member.otherInfo+"</li>")
             }

        }
    }




$("#mainContainer").orgChart({container: $("#main"),interactive: true, fade: true, speed: 'slow'}); 

}); 


</script>


</head>
<body>
<div  style="display: none">


<ul id="mainContainer" class="clearfix"></ul>   

</div>
<div id="main">

</div>


</body>


</html>
```